# Server side browser sniffing for IE 11 in .NET

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, browser-detection, internet-explorer-11

Before the release of IE11, I have been using

```
context.Request.Browser.Browser == "IE"
```

to detect the IE browser on the server end. 
Since IE11 has user agent changes, now using the same technique doesn't work anymore.

Is regular expression on context.Request.Browser.UserAgent only choice?

Comment: Visit your page with IE11 and look at the `Browser` object's value? `Browser.Browser` is `InternetExplorer` and `Browser.Version` is `11.0`. What is your question?

Comment: It is not InternetExplorer any more it says 'Mozilla'

Comment: Ok... my IE 11 here says InternetExplorer.

Comment: Here is the image:
http://imgur.com/Rbiv3rK

Comment: Microsoft have changed the UA string because they don't really want you to "special case" IE any more. They want it to get the same code as Firefox/Chrome/Safari/etc these days. That said, I believe there's a hotfix for .net servers which fixes this issue. This one perhaps? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us

Answer (score 0):

First why do you need to browser sniff in the first place. You really should not do that, instead do feature detection in the client and adjust from there. Here is how to check if the browser 'cuts the mustard'

```
        <script>

        if (!('querySelector' in document)  //this should work in ie 9+
             || !('localStorage' in window)  //ie 8+
             || !('addEventListener' in window)  //ie 8 + (I think)
            || !('matchMedia' in window)) {//ie 10+

            //do your redirect here
        }

    </script>
```

With that said here is a method I built to detect if it is obsolete IE or not. Basically it checks if the browser is 'IE' and the major version is 10. If it is not 10 then it is 9,8,7. IE 11 returns 'Internet Explorer' so you know it is good to go.

```
        public static bool IsOldIE()
    {

        var Browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
        var isIE = Browser.Browser == "IE";

        if (!isIE)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Browser.MajorVersion != 10;

    }
```

Comment: FYI - Partial PDF Rendering doesn't work very well in IE as comparatively to other browsers. That's the sole reason I have to check for the browser.

Comment: what is partial PDF rendering? I never had an issue opening a PDF document and I have never heard of partial PDF rendering? When you open a PDF it would open your PDF client.